# Search for products in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText InputString;
    private Button btnScan, btnSearch;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        InputString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Scan);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Search);
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String checkString = "InputString";

                Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("Stock").orderByChild("productName").orderByChild("productId").equalTo(checkString);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                      setContentView(R.layout.activity_product__detail_);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: I am saving the data as follow in Firebase,]

I want to do let the users search if the users key in the "Product name", "Product code" or using "barcode" to search the product and then the application will display the product detail.For example, the users enter "mild steel", the application will display the product name, product code, barcode and the quantity

Comment: Do you have code so far you want to show, or tried? Even if it's wrong, please add it

Comment: Please go through some tutorial on Firebase. This is not a homework portal. Please implement something and ask questions if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: For future reference, this is called a Query and is covered in the Firebase Getting Started Guide: [Working with Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) see the Filtering Data section

Answer (score 0):

Here sample code

```
final String checkString = "inputString";

Query query = mDatabase.child("user").orderByChild("productName").equalTo(checkString);

 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mDatabase.child("e-inventory-store").chile("Stock")
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
  ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String productName = map.get("productName");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Try this one,